# ASP.NET MVC: how to parse url string to get RouteData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

Is there any way to get RouteData from a url string?

I have login form with returlUrl as query string parameter.
My routes are defined as : `{languageCode}/{controller}/{action}`

In action method `LogIn(string returlUrl)` the returlUrl is something like "en/home/contacts" etc.
I need to change languagePart a i dont want to use string.Replace, as routes may change in future.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to parse it so you can do a redirect later?

Comment: @ : i need to redirect user to the returnUrl, but in different languageCode than was in original returnUrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This forums thread might be useful: http://forums.asp.net/t/1281667.aspx

This is the best option I can think of off the top of my head.  Bascially, using RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData and Mocking HttpContextBase based on your Url string.

Answer (score 4):

So this is an old thread obviously, but for anyone else coming to this question via Google, I just wrote a blog post about a way to do this pretty easily. I actually came across this question on SO when I was attempting to find a way to do this myself but I didn't find one that I liked so I wrote my own.

[Creating a RouteData Instance from a URL](http://www.scottschluer.com/creating-a-routedata-instance-from-a-url/)

Comment: Scott, it looks like your link is broken.

Comment: Link is still broken.